# Azure Function freezes(?)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a function in Azure Functions app, on App service plan.

My function is in python. It contains a loop that consumes data from twitter API using tweepy module and write the results to a local temp file, before saving them to a file in Azure Storage (I use AppenedBlobService for this).

**Problem**

The problem is sometimes my function just freeze(?). It would make requests, get results, save results then just freeze at any time. It doesn't stop, when I look at Monitor pane, it's still running (the three blue dots). The only way to stop it is I have to restart an instance (and after a while, blue dots become orange exclamation mark). It doesn't show any error, neither does it produce any result. It raises no exception, finally block doesn't get executed, it feels like the function is just there, not executing the new line, not stopping, nothing.

What's totally baffling is that this happens at different steps during executions. Sometimes it happens when calling an API (so it looks like that method never returns), sometimes when checking blob existence in Storage (done via BlockBlobService), sometimes when saving the results.

**Assumption**

My assumption was that there is something wrong with the API. However, when I tested locally, there is NO problem with an API. I can make lots of consecutive requests without any problem, while it would freeze after 3-5 requests in Azure Function. (It's also much slower.)
So another possibility is that saving file to Storage went wrong, but the thing is, there are times when it DOES save the results correctly. It saves, then loop back to API call and get stuck, or it finished API call and get stuck, not saving or anything.

*Everything works perfectly fine in local environment* so I really don't know how to continue here. I tried to trace it by printing out between each step, and I discovered where it hangs as mentioned above, but it still doesn't tell why it hangs because sometimes that chunk of code works just fine.

Any suggestion on what the problem might be, or how I should debug this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:

This is a problem due to the version of python used by app service / functions (`2.7.8`) and the `urllib3` module, see [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings). The errors which are crashing the app can be ignored or logged until web apps updates the version of python.

You can bring a custom version of python to functions: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Using-a-custom-version-of-Python

---

It's possible that there are concurrency issues with the apis. Whenever possible, try moving all logic to input / output bindings. Also, you could try to limit concurrency. Consider using a storage queue trigger and setting batchSize to 1 (no concurrency) in your [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json).

Looking at logs there are a few errors with your function coming from the tweepy library.

[Here](http://markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions) is an article about accessing logs, or you can directly take a look at `<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugConsole` -> `LogFiles/Application/Functions`. You can also change logging behavior via [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json).

Comment: There is always only one item in the queue when that happens. It'd be great if you could have a look into my function. Site: http://data-analysis.azurewebsites.net/, function name ends with _search

Comment: I have already looked at logs from LogFiles/Applicaton/Functions and it doesn't have any more info than in Function portal (which just stops printing anything at some steps). In Kudu, those invocation logs are the same as what is shown in Monitor pane. When my function freezes, the status is "never finish" and thus have no information other than binding parameters value and context. Could direct me to where exactly I can find those tweepy error logs?